# undefined reference to `palloc'

Tags: c, postgresql

I am trying to compile and link a function example from PostgreSQL manual:

```
#include "postgres.h"   /* this includes directly palloc.h */
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "utils/geo_decls.h"    /* point type */

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(makepoint);
Datum makepoint(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
   Point *pointx = PG_GETARG_POINT_P(0);
   Point *pointy = PG_GETARG_POINT_P(1);
   Point *new_point = (Point *) palloc(sizeof(Point));
   new_point->x = pointx->x;
   new_point->y = pointy->y;
   PG_RETURN_POINT_P(new_point);
}
```

I have compiled it with command:

```
cc -c -fPIC -DHAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64 -I/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/11.2.2/include/server -I/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/11.2.2/include/server/port/win32 ../src/makepoint.c
```

apparently it compiles finely, but when linking:

```
cc -shared -o makepoint.so makepoint.o
```

The following error arises:

```
makepoint.o:makepoint.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `palloc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The compiler is

```
cc.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 8.2.1 20181207
installed in MSYS on Windows 10.
```

(The same error arises with gcc or g++)
Please, help me understand what I mistakenly do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually you must link with `postgres.lib` on Windows. Not sure about MinGW.

Comment: Don't you need the "-fPIC" option on the linking stage too?

Comment: @ChrisTurner, he does need to use `-fPIC`, as he is producing shared position independent code. As he shows, he uses it on compiling, not on linking (look at the `-c` compiler option :) )

Answer (score 4):

While you've correctly included the headers needed to compile against the PostgreSQL library, you are not linking any of the shared libraries needed to create the final executable. You should change your final compile command to something like the following for gcc on Linux:

```
cc -c -fPIC makepoint.c -o makepoint.o
cc -shared --relocatable -o libmakepoint.so makepoint.o
cc -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpq -L. -lmakepoint -o myapp.exe main.c
```

You will then need to make sure your local directory where `libmakepoint.so` is located is available to the dynamic linker at runtime by either defining the path in your environment's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or adding a configuration to `ld_config`.  You can read more about that process [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html).

Note that your installation directories may differ depending on how you've installed PostgreSQL, as well as your platform, but since you're using MSYS2, you should be able to install `pkg-config`, and use the various `--cflags`, `--includedir`, `--libs`, and `--libdir` commands to get the appropriate search directories and names of the libraries to link to.  For instance:

```
pkg-config --libs libpq
```

will output (depending on your configuration):

```
-L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpq
```

and you can then add that string into your build command to link against the correct libraries as well as point the compiler to the correct library path.

Finally, you can [reference this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-build.html) for additional build instructions.

Comment: He's not building an executable though, so I'm not sure how any of this is relevant?

Comment: On my system the Object Code Libraries are installed at C:/applications/PostgreSQL/11.2.2/lib.
Accordingly I have tried to link with the command:
`cc -shared -L/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/11.2.2/lib -lpq -o makepoint.so makepoint.o`,  but the same error message was shown: 
`makepoint.o:makepoint.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to 'palloc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Correct, you only need to link the libraries when building an executable, which he must be doing at some point if he's getting undefined reference errors ... I've updated my answer to reflect the building of the shared library and the final compile command

Answer (score 0):

You've put the `-fPIC` option on the wrong stage of building the shared object. It needs to go on the linking stage, not the compilation stage. Like this...

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o makepoint.so makepoint.o
```

Comment: I've tried to link using `-fPIC` option too, but the same error appears.

Comment: What happens if you skip the step building the object file and build the .so from the C file itself? ie: `cc -fPIC -DHAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64 -I/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/11.2.2/include/server -I/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/11.2.2/include/server/port/win32 ../src/makepoint.c -shared -o makepoint.so`

Comment: I've tried as you suggest to do, but got the same error. I tried to include `-L/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/11.3.1/lib` option too but nothing changed. I've doubted the library 11.2.2 for some reason did not contain palloc definition, so I updated the PostgreSQL installation to today's last version, that is 11.3.1.  but neither did this attempt help.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the linker then if it won't work even if you tell it to use the library.

Comment: I've updated entire MSYS2 and all relative C/C++ compilers. Codes not including palloc function are compiled and linked successfully as before, but with palloc the same error pops out.

Answer (score 0):

So, to compile, the following command should be used:

```
cc -fPIC -DHAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64 -c ../src/makepoint.c -I/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/12.0/include/server -I/C:/applications/PostgreSQL/12.0/include/server/port/win32
```

and then to link:

```
cc -shared -o makepoint.so makepoint.o -L/c/applications/PostgreSQL/12.0/lib -l postgres
```